# View logs for non-interactive shell script?

Tags: bash, logs, command-history

I have some scripts that work perfectly when I invoke them directly but not when invoked via a keyboard macro.

I've tired looking at bash logs and history but I don't think those locations only show information about scripts I directly invoked.

How can I find logs and history about my scripts that I'm not invoking directly?

Comment: There are no logs, unless the scripts do that manually, or something about how the scripts are run collects any output, or if you point `strace` or `sysdig` at them.

Comment: if you don't want to edit the script to add logging, then edit  they key macro; `/home/user/bin/script.sh &>/home/user/temp.log` and check the log, then edit the key map back.

Comment: @mikejonsey thx I'm trying and the log is created but it's always black even for a script that returns an error normally.